# NSSortDescriptor with Comparator using actual object not a key value

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I have an entity in CoreData `MyObject` which has properties `latitude` and `longitude`.

I'd like to perform a fetch with an `NSFetchedResultsController` that sorts the fetch by the distance the `MyObject` is from the user's current location.

However, I don't know what to put in the `Key` part of the sort descriptor.

I don't want to compare a particular key of the object. I want to compare the objects themselves.

I'm not sure how it's possible for me to do this without repopulating the distance field of the records.

I'm trying to use this code...

```
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"." ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(MyObject *object1, MyObject *opject2) {
    // stuff here
}];
```

But it crashes the app due to memory pressure (lol).

Obviously using `@"."` is not correct but is there a way of doing this?

Or is there a better way of doing this using a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to sort the objects by their keys but instead sort the objects themselves  then you should not use Sort descriptors. Just get the array of the results and then sort that array. Of course your custom object MyObject should implement isEqual in order to do this.

Another alternative is to add a new key called `distance` to the MyObject and then use it as the key for the sort descriptor.

1. Create NSFetchRequest for the MyObject entities from the CoreData
2. `executeFetchRequest` to fetch all the locations in the database.
3. Iterate thru the MyObject array and populate the distance property by calculating the distance between the currentLocation and the MyObject's location (lat,long)
4. Set the sortDescriptor of the fetch request created in 1 to `distance`
5. Create a FRC using this fetch request and call `performFetch`
6. Use the `fetchedObjects` of the FRC which will be in sorted order according to the `distance`.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Yeah your second solution is probably what I'm going to do. The problem with getting them all out and then sorting them is that it breaks the whole concept of using a fetchedresultscontroller.

Comment: Actually it does not..The reason is that you have to probably calculate the distance every time anyways since the current location can change. So you will have to fetch all the existing (lat,long) objects using `executeFetchRequest`. Then iterate thru those objects and populate the distance property. Then create a fetched results controller and use the distance as the sort descriptor and call `performFetch` on the FRC to get the sorted results by distance

Comment: Ah, I guess so. I either update into core data where I have to fetch them all or fetch them all and then sort them. OK, cool, thanks